# CORS error when I try to call a Lambda tied to an API Gateway route

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have API Gateway setup in AWS with various routes, one of which (/profile/general/{+proxy} hits an express server hosted on a lambda.
Let's say the base/invoke url for the API Gateway stage is https://xyz.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev . There is a route in the express server like this:

app.js:

```
    app.get("/profile", async function (req, res) {
      console.log("req from lambda app.js: ", req); 
      try {
           res.json({ "test": "hello "});
         } catch (err) {
           res.json({ "error": err });  
         }
   }
```

the express server on the lambda also has middleware that should be handling CORS -

middleware.js

```
   const configureCors = (route) => {
      route.use(function (req, res, next) {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
      next();
    });
    return route;
  };
```

Likewise, in the API Gateway, there are Enable CORS settings with:

- Options checked
- Access-control-allow-methods with Get,Head, Options
- Access-control-allow-headers with 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'
- Access-control-allow-origin with 'x'

However, I cannot hit the endpoint from my react app in localhost when I try a GET request to https://xyz.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/profile/general . When I try the request from Localhost/React, I get a CORS error. The request events from React don't even show up in CloudWatch logs for the lambda. So, where does the issue seem to be? Or what other info can I provide?

Thanks

Comment: That url doesn't load for me, check the error logs

Comment: Can you call the URL directly from your browser? Start with that. I haven't tried putting an Express server in a nested route but am questioning what the path would be when it hits the server. I guess it would depend on how you are wrapping Express but `app.get("/profile...` might mean `profile/general/profile`. Not sure though - some stuff to look at

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a formatting error in the code rather than anything to do with CORs.

Checking format here can help to locate the problem

https://codebeautify.org/python-formatter-beautifier